# UnknownHost on trying to POST -- Android

Tags: android, networking, http-post

Anyone have any ideas why this might be failing? The URL is accessible from my browser, but I get a host-not-found exception when I try to POST from within my app.

```
public void postData() {  
    //http://www.softwarepassion.com/android-series-get-post-and-multipart-post-requests/
    File f = new File(filename);
    try {
             HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();  
             String postURL = "http://dragonox.cs.ucsb.edu/Mosaic3D/clientupload.php";


             HttpPost post = new HttpPost(postURL); 
             List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);  
             nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("project", "globetrotter-test-00"));  
             nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", "globetrotter-test-00.jpg"));  
             post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));  

             FileBody bin = new FileBody(f);
             MultipartEntity reqEntity = new MultipartEntity(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);  
             reqEntity.addPart("file", bin);
             post.setEntity(reqEntity); 

             HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);  
             HttpEntity resEntity = response.getEntity();  
             if (resEntity != null) {    
                       Log.i("RESPONSE",EntityUtils.toString(resEntity));
                 }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


}
```

[image: UnknownHostException]

Comment: I can reach the site from my phone's browser too...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try setting

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>`

in your [`AndroidManifest.xml`](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/SampleSyncAdapter/AndroidManifest.html) file

Comment: Yeah, I just realized that a few moments ago. Derp. Thanks.